# Merge multidimensional NumPy arrays based on first row

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have to work with sensor data (from ros, specifically, but it should not be relevant). To this end, I have several 2-D numpy arrays with one row storing the timestamps and the following others the corresponding sensors data. Problem is, such arrays do not have the same dimensions (different sampling times). I need to merge all of these arrays into a single big one. How can I do so based on the timestamp and, say, replace the missing numbers with 0 or NaN?

Example of my situation:

```
import numpy as np

time1=np.arange(1,10)
data1=np.random.randint(200, size=time1.shape)

a=np.array((time1,data1))
print(a)

time2=np.arange(1,10,2)
data2=np.random.randint(200, size=time2.shape)

b=np.array((time2,data2))

print(b)
```

Which returns output

```
[[  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9]
 [ 51   9 117 174 164  60  95 197  30]]

[[  1   3   5   7   9]
 [ 35 188 114 153  36]]
```

What I am looking for is

```
[[  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9]
 [ 51   9 117 174 164  60  95 197  30]
 [ 35   0 188   0 114   0 153   0  36]]
```

Is there any way to achieve this in an efficient way? This is an example but I am working with thousands of samples. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### For simple case of one b-matrix

With first row of `a` storing all possible timestamps and both of those first rows in `a` and `b` being sorted, we can use [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) -

```
idx = np.searchsorted(a[0],b[0])
out_dtype = np.result_type((a.dtype,b.dtype))
b0 = np.zeros(a.shape[1],dtype=out_dtype)
b0[idx] = b[1]
out = np.vstack((a,b0))
```

---

#### For several b-matrices

**Approach #1**

To extend to multiple *b-matrices*, we can follow a similar method with `np.searchsorted` within a loop, like so -

```
def merge_arrays(a, B):
    # a : Array with first row holding all possible timestamps
    # B : list or tuple of all b-matrices
    
    lens = np.array([len(i) for i in B])
    L = (lens-1).sum() + len(a)
    out_dtype = np.result_type(*[i.dtype for i in B])
    out = np.zeros((L, a.shape[1]), dtype=out_dtype)
    out[:len(a)] = a
    s = len(a)
    for b_i in B:
        idx = np.searchsorted(a[0],b_i[0])
        out[s:s+len(b_i)-1,idx] = b_i[1:]
        s += len(b_i)-1
    return out
```

Sample run -

```
In [175]: a
Out[175]: 
array([[ 4, 11, 16, 22, 34, 56, 67, 87, 91, 99],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10]])

In [176]: b0
Out[176]: 
array([[16, 22, 34, 56, 67, 91],
       [20, 80, 69, 79, 47, 64],
       [82, 88, 49, 29, 19, 19]])

In [177]: b1
Out[177]: 
array([[ 4, 16, 34, 99],
       [28, 34,  0,  0],
       [36, 53,  5, 38],
       [17, 79,  4, 42]])

In [178]: merge_arrays(a, [b0,b1])
Out[178]: 
array([[ 4, 11, 16, 22, 34, 56, 67, 87, 91, 99],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [ 0,  0, 20, 80, 69, 79, 47,  0, 64,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 82, 88, 49, 29, 19,  0, 19,  0],
       [28,  0, 34,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [36,  0, 53,  0,  5,  0,  0,  0,  0, 38],
       [17,  0, 79,  0,  4,  0,  0,  0,  0, 42]])
```

**Approach #2**

If looping with `np.searchsorted` seems to be the bottleneck, we can vectorize that part -

```
def merge_arrays_v2(a, B):
    # a : Array with first row holding all possible timestamps
    # B : list or tuple of all b-matrices
    
    lens = np.array([len(i) for i in B])
    L = (lens-1).sum() + len(a)
    out_dtype = np.result_type(*[i.dtype for i in B])
    out = np.zeros((L, a.shape[1]), dtype=out_dtype)
    out[:len(a)] = a
    s = len(a)
    
    r0 = [i[0] for i in B]
    r0s = np.concatenate((r0))
    idxs = np.searchsorted(a[0],r0s)
    
    cols = np.array([i.shape[1] for i in B])
    sp = np.r_[0,cols.cumsum()]
    start,stop = sp[:-1],sp[1:]
    for (b_i,s0,s1) in zip(B,start,stop):
        idx = idxs[s0:s1]
        out[s:s+len(b_i)-1,idx] = b_i[1:]
        s += len(b_i)-1
    return out
```

Comment: This is really useful, thanks! However, how is it possible to do this operation on multiple matrices and without knowing the largest one (i.e., the one with most samples)?

Comment: @Bianca Would it be based on the first rows again? Also, would all of those be sorted?

Comment: yes, based on the first row. And yes they are sorted, imagine several matrices 'b' as in the example, all with different sampling times

Comment: @Bianca Also, can we assume that all timestamps from all b-matrices are contained in first row of `a`?

Comment: We can assume we have one vector containing all timestamps, then several matrices that have some samples, with different frequencies

Comment: Is the order in which they are "merged" relevant? @bianca I mean taking into account that they all merge with the largest

Comment: But the `b` matrices may have different shape no @divakar ?

Comment: @Bianca Would those b-matrices have different shapes?

Comment: They have different shapes yes, as the number of rows can also vary

Comment: Nice soln @divakar I think I overcomplicated mine a little assuming we dont know which array is `A`. As if having different shaped arrays didn't complicate it enough :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach using [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html):

```
time1=np.arange(1,10)
data1=np.random.randint(200, size=time1.shape)

a=np.array((time1,data1))
# array([[  1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9],
#        [118, 105,  86,  94,  69,  17, 142,  46,  54]])

time2=np.arange(1,10,2)
data2=np.random.randint(200, size=time2.shape)
b=np.array((time2,data2))
# array([[ 1,  3,  5,  7,  9],
#        [70, 15,  4, 97, 57]])
```

---

```
out = np.vstack([a, np.zeros(a.shape[1])])
out[out.shape[0]-1, np.searchsorted(a[0], b[0])] = b[1]

array([[  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.],
       [118., 105.,  86.,  94.,  69.,  17., 142.,  46.,  54.],
       [ 70.,   0.,  15.,   0.,   4.,   0.,  97.,   0.,  57.]])
```

---

**Update - Merging many matrices**

Here's a almost fully vectorised approach for a scenario with multiple `b` matrices. This approach does not require a priori knowledge of which is the largest list:

```
def merge_timestamps(*x):
    # infer which is the list with maximum length
    # as well as individual lengths
    concat = np.concatenate(*x, axis=1)[0]
    lens = np.r_[np.flatnonzero(np.diff(concat) < 0), len(concat)]
    max_len_list = np.r_[lens[0], np.diff(lens)].argmax()
    # define the output matrix 
    A = x[0][max_len_list]
    out = np.vstack([A[1], np.zeros((len(*x)-1, len(A[0])))])
    others = np.flatnonzero(~np.in1d(np.arange(len(*x)), max_len_list))
    # Update the output matrix with the values of the smaller
    # arrays according to their index. This is of course assuming 
    # all values are contained in the largest
    for ix, i in enumerate(others):
        out[-(ix+1), x[0][i][0]-A[0].min()] = x[0][i][1]
    return out
```

---

Lets check with the following example:

```
time1=np.arange(1,10)
data1=np.random.randint(200, size=time1.shape)

a=np.array((time1,data1))

# array([[  1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9],
#        [107,  13, 123, 119, 137, 135,  65, 157,  83]])

time2=np.arange(1,10,2)
data2=np.random.randint(200, size=time2.shape)
b = np.array((time2,data2))
# array([[  1,   3,   5,   7,   9],
#        [ 81,  49,  83,  32, 179]])

time3=np.arange(1,4,2)
data3=np.random.randint(200, size=time3.shape)
c=np.array((time3,data3))
# array([[  1,   3],
#        [185, 117]])
```

---

```
merge_timestamps([a,b,c])

array([[  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.],
       [107.,  13., 123., 119., 137., 135.,  65., 157.,  83.],
       [185.,   0., 117.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [ 81.,   0.,  49.,   0.,  83.,   0.,  32.,   0., 179.]])
```

---

As mentioned this approach does not require a priori knowledge of which is the largest list, i.e.  it would also work with:

```
merge_timestamps([b, c, a])

array([[  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.],
       [107.,  13., 123., 119., 137., 135.,  65., 157.,  83.],
       [185.,   0., 117.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [ 81.,   0.,  49.,   0.,  83.,   0.,  32.,   0., 179.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Applicable only if sensor is capturing data at fixed interval.
First we will need to create a dataframe with fixed interval (15 min interval in this case), then use `concat` function to this dataframe with sensor's data.

Code to generate dataframe with 15 min interval (copied)

```
l = (pd.DataFrame(columns=['NULL'],
                  index=pd.date_range('2016-09-02T17:30:00Z', '2016-09-02T21:00:00Z',
                                      freq='15T'))
       .between_time('07:00','21:00')
       .index.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
       .tolist()
)
l = pd.DataFrame(l)
```

Assuming below data comes from sensor

```
m = (pd.DataFrame(columns=['NULL'],
                  index=pd.date_range('2016-09-02T17:30:00Z', '2016-09-02T21:00:00Z',
                                      freq='30T'))
       .between_time('07:00','21:00')
       .index.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
       .tolist()
)
m = pd.DataFrame(m)
m['SensorData'] = np.arange(8)
```

`merge` above two dataframes

```
df = l.merge(m, left_on = 0, right_on= 0,how='left')
df.loc[df['SensorData'].isna() == True,'SensorData'] = 0
```

Output

```
                       0  SensorData
0   2016-09-02T17:30:00Z         0.0
1   2016-09-02T17:45:00Z         0.0
2   2016-09-02T18:00:00Z         1.0
3   2016-09-02T18:15:00Z         0.0
4   2016-09-02T18:30:00Z         2.0
5   2016-09-02T18:45:00Z         0.0
6   2016-09-02T19:00:00Z         3.0
7   2016-09-02T19:15:00Z         0.0
8   2016-09-02T19:30:00Z         4.0
9   2016-09-02T19:45:00Z         0.0
10  2016-09-02T20:00:00Z         5.0
11  2016-09-02T20:15:00Z         0.0
12  2016-09-02T20:30:00Z         6.0
13  2016-09-02T20:45:00Z         0.0
14  2016-09-02T21:00:00Z         7.0
```